# Find SQL Server 2008 computed column dependency

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, calculated-columns

I want to search whether a columns is participating in a computed column expression.

I came up with this

```
SELECT 
    (select name 
     from sys.columns 
     where column_id = sys.sql_expression_dependencies.referencing_minor_id 
     and object_id = sys.sql_expression_dependencies.referencing_id) as [dependant_column]
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies
WHERE referencing_minor_id > 0 
    and referencing_class = 1 
    and referenced_class = 1 
    and object_name(referencing_id) = 'trns1'
    and referenced_minor_id = (select column_id 
                           from sys.columns 
                           where name = 'class1' 
                           and OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = 'trns1')
```

Please help.

Comment: It would help if you explained what the problem/error is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to look at the sys.computed_columns table:

```
select name, definition 
from sys.computed_columns
```

This is a very similar question: [SQL Server: Computed Column defintions retrievable from Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047099/sql-server-computed-column-defintions-retrievable-from-database)

There are probably some more kicking around.